# Xcode 11 - UITableViewCell not resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What happened to self-sizing UITableViewCell in Xcode 11 ?

I can't make it resize based on label content size.

All the vertical views in cell are pinned appropriately. Number of lines is 0.

[image]

And in viewController:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

There was another case when I managed to make cell self-sizing (the cell was created programmatically) only after I added the label as subview to `ContentView`, but in this particular case I need the label to be placed inside the gray view.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please show the constraint you added to View that has the label.Also show what constraints you added to the labels inside the View.

Comment: All the constraints are pinned vertically, I have collected this kind of cells a 1000 times, but starting from xcode 11 I can't figure what's going on. All the elements are pinned vertically to each other and the light gray container view is pinned on top and bottom also

Comment: does the image have bottom constraint too ?

Comment: yes, it has top and bottom spacing with the light gray view

Comment: Is the concern the rendering of the NIB within IB, or when the app is actually running? Assuming it is the latter, there’s simply not enough shown here to reproduce your problem. We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).